# How do I find the equivalent resistance using symmetry?

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistance

[image]

I know this could be solved using delta-to-y transformation, but I want to solve this using symmetry.

Considering the middle line the symmetry axis this becomes:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdbtQWm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Then, you see the we have the equivalent resistance: (1 + 0.5 + 0.5) + (0.5) = 2.5 ohms.

What's the problem?

Answer (score 5):

If you draw it a bit different, it's easy to see that there is no current flowing through the middle resistor.  (It's a bridge with equal R's in all the arms.) So you can remove the central R from the circuit.  From there it's easy.

Answer (score 0):

First add the 1 ohm resistances which are in direct link with arms a,b. That gives 2 ohm . Now for the rest of the circuit , its a wheatstone bridge with an equivalent resistance of R = 2*2/(2+2)=1 ohm. Adding all three we get Req=1+1+1=3 ohm.